# Adding layout constraint programatically in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

In my view controller `[viewDidLoad]` I am creating and adding a subview programatically.

```
self.mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:self.mainViewController.view];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.mainViewController.view];
[self addChildViewController:self.mainViewController];
[self.mainViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This works fine, but it doesn't render great due to auto layout being turned on. I want the subview to fill it's parent's entire frame so I add some constraints.

```
NSDictionary *views = @{@"view" : self.mainViewController.view};
NSArray *vertical = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[view]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
NSArray *horizontal = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[view]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[self.mainViewController.view addConstraints:vertical];
[self.mainViewController.view addConstraints:horizontal];
```

which throws

```
The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9c9bd330b0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f9c9bc3bc30]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f9c9bf83fa0 )>
When added to a view, the constraint\'s items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
```

So my understanding is that the parent view has not finished building, or at least its relationship with the programatically created subview. Therefore it is not possible to add layout constraints between them. The question is then, if I have understood correctly, how else can I create this subview and add it automatically after the parent vc is loaded?

Comment: Try adding the constraints to self.view.

Comment: that works, thanks! however they aren't correct i.e. the subview doesn't fill the parent. do you know what's wrong with my constraints?

Comment: What does it look like? What if you try |[view]| without the -0- ?

Comment: it's a little short and too wide

Comment: Try doing it in UIView didMoveToSuperview if superview is not nil

Comment: viewDidLoad only means the view is in memory loaded from the nib. It doesn't mean it has been added to a hierarchy of views

Comment: You can do the same in viewDidAppear from the view controller

Comment: Does the mainViewController view have width or height constraints that would prevent it from filling it's container?

Comment: Simplest way is to add the subview in storyboard, set constraints to its main view. then create a property for the subview using which you can add any other object to it...